# What are the Pravaras used at the time of sankalpam?

Tags: history, sankalpa, gotra

What are the Pravaras used at the time of Sankalpam? I used to utter srimukh shandilya gotrah Tri Pravarah.
Is there any scripture which define Pravara?

Comment: Visit [Pravaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravaras). [Btw](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34700392#34700392), what is your Shakha?

Comment: @Pandya I am not confirm but most probably Sama Veda

Comment: Ok. You may continue discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy)

Comment: @Pandya yes sure

Comment: I don't think Scriptures define Pravaras, A bramhana should know it from his ancestors. Although there is a possibility of finding Pravara or Shakha Rishis in Upanishadic Guruparampara.

Comment: You should say .......Trayaarsheyeya pravaraanvita. Shandilya gotrah ..... sutrah...Samavedodyayi your name Ahambho abhivaadaye during the sandhyavandanam.

Comment: Btw, [this article of GadyaKosha](http://gadyakosh.org/gk/गोत्र,_प्रवर_और_साधारण_होम_/_ब्रह्मर्षि_वंश_विस्तार_/_सहजानन्द_सरस्वती) (witten by Sahjananda Sarasvati) provides useful information regarding Gotra and Pravara. They mention Three Pravaras of Shandilya Gotra - Shandilya, Asita and Devala.

Comment: @Pandya This is great info.