# PRAVARA & SUTHRA - RIG-VED- JAMADAGNI GOTRA

Tags: vedas

GOTRA:JAMADAGNI
VED:RIGVEDA
BHRMINS:SMARATHA

WHAT IS THE PRAVARA & SUTHRA

Comment: PRAVARA ;Bhargava Chyavana APNAVANA AURAVA JAMADAGNYA

Comment: What is the SUTHRAS for this pravara?

Comment: You should use lowercase letters in your question. Don't ask in all caps.

Comment: Veda:Rig veda, Gotra:Jamadagni, Brahmin:Smartha

Comment: what is the pravara & suthra for the above?

Comment: Pravara: may be; Bhargava,Chyavana,apnavana,Aurava,Jamadagnya

Comment: Check [What are the Pravaras used at the time of sankalpam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13554/3500). Although question is unanswered, you should now ask what is Sutra alone, since it is partial duplicate.